# Excluding interface generation for ifdef code block

Tags: c++, swig

I am trying to generate Go interface for a C++ library. One of the library header has code block like this

**library.h**

```
...
#ifndef DISABLE_FEATURE_X
  struct TypeX
  {
    TypeX();
    {
      ...
    }
  };
#endif
...
```

Then I include the header in the interface like below

**library.i**

```
%{
  #include <library.h>
%}
...
%include <library.h>
```

When I generate Go interface with macro DISABLE_FEATURE_X defined, Swig generates interface code for `TypeX` even though it is excluded by the macro `DISABLE_FEATURE_X`.

How do I tell Swig to exclude the code block while generating the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to define the macro inside the SWIG interface, so that the SWIG preprocessor doesn't see the functions:

```
%{
  #include <library.h>
%}
...
#define DISABLE_FEATURE_X
%include <library.h>
```

should do the trick.

SWIG itself does also support the -D command line argument, so if you'd rather you could also call `swig -DDISABLE_FEATURE_X ...` just like you would for a compiler

Comment: This is also backed up by the comments in github [here](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/776).